# Creating a floorplan in Excel using an X-Y scatter

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a bunch of X and Y coordinates, and I would like to make a floorplan out of it. For that, I'm using an XY-scatter. This is working fine, but I would like to have the names of the nodes on top of the nodes, instead of the Y coordinates. Is that possible?

Just as an example, hereby the following screenshot:

[image: Example screenshot]

As you can guess, I would like to have a, b, c and d in top of the dots instead of 4, 2, 5 and 1.

Is that possible in Excel?

**Edit after first answer:**
My Excel version does not have a "Value From Cells" checkbox, as you can see from this screenshot:

[image]

My Excel version is (windows explorer "Excel.exe" file, right-click, "Details" tab) "16.0.12527.21416". (Why did they remove the "Help, about"???).

Comment: Help > About is now File > Options > somewhere   *(dynamic human memory has refresh problems!)*

Comment: Try repairing your Excel and see if that option comes back. If not, then perhaps uninstall/reinstall.

Comment: File > Account > About Excel shows your version. 16.0.any.build should have this, since it came out iirc in Excel 2013 (15.0).

Comment: @JonPeltier: my Excel version is Microsoft Excel for Office 365 MSO (16.0.12527.21378) 32-bit.

Comment: Your version indicates that the Value From Cells option is available, I don't know why it is not. Try restarting Excel, opening a new workbook, entering some simple data like you showed above, and trying again. If that doesn't work, try repairing Office.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click the existing labels and select `Format Data Labels`.

[image]

Remove the tick from `Y Value` and place a tick in `Value From Cells` - you can then select the range you want to show in the labels.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but my Excel version does not seem to support that feature.

Comment: Try using the [The XY Chart Labeler](http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/ChartLabeler.htm).

Answer (score 0):

The best answer is [Jon Peltier's](https://superuser.com/users/95825/jon-peltier) comment above-if he adds it as an answer you should accept it (and you should check out his blog also).  Absent that, there is another way-it's just more cumbersome.

For each node that you want labeled, you'll need to add it as a separate series, with it's name as the series name.  Then, just choose the series name option for the data label.  You'll likely want those points added twice-once for their role in the floorplan, especially if you're using lines between the points, and again as the label you want.

Comment: Would the downvoter like to give some constructive criticism to improve the answer?